# Invoke constructor with parameter in MVVM light SimpleIOC

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I have just started using SimpleIOC from mvvm light toolkit. I was just wondering is there an option to make a parameterised constructor as a PreferredConstructor?

Is this feature available with SimpleIOC? If so, how would I pass parameter when attempting to resolve an object from container.

I can easily do this for parameter less constructor as like-

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyClass>();
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyClass>().MyMethod();
```

But, question is how can I achieve this for a constructor with parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the Abstract Factory pattern.

You basically create an `IMyClassFactory` interface and implement it in the application layer. Your classes will have `IMyClassFactory` as dependency, instead of `MyClass`.

```
public interface IMyClassFactory 
{
    // For simplification it returns MyClass. For sake of decoupling, 
    // it should return IMyClass interface which is implemented by MyClass
    MyClass Create(string myParameter);
}

// In your application layer, if you use n-layered architecture
public class MyClassFactory : IMyClassFactory 
{
    public MyClass Create(string myParameter) 
    {
        return new MyClass(
            SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Dependency1>(),
            SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Dependency2>(),
            myParameter
        );
    }
}
```

And in your ViewModel just do

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    private readonly MyClass myClass;
    public SomeViewModel(IMyClassFactory myClassFactory) 
    {
        myClass = myClassFactory.Create("MyParameter");
    }
}
```

On a side note: Don't use Singleton for IoC, it somewhat beats the purpose of the IoC container and it becomes a mere ServiceLocator.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, does this suffice 'not creating multiple objects' which IOC does very basically? When I invoke myClassFactory.Create("MyParameter") twice, doesn't it produce two different objects?

Comment: Dunno for SimpleIoC, but Unity 3 you can also override parameters. `this.unityContainer.Resolve<MyClass>(
        new ParameterOverride("myParameter", passedParameter));` though that won't result in a new instance if that type was registered as Singleton before. Any specific reason why MyClass needs to be singleton? Of course you could also implement your own caching mechanism within the IMyClassFactory and cache instances by parameter. The nice thing is, this isn't a concern for your ViewModel and is transparently abstracted in the MyClassFactory implementation.

Comment: You can also use named instance registration (I assume SimpleIoC supports it. Unity3 does for sure) after registering it, then it's an IoC concern

Comment: Shouldn't MyClassFactory get the dependencies in the constructor, using dependency injection instead of relying on SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance, since that "beats the purpose of the IoC container"?

Comment: You can do it so too yeah. Though it depends a bit on the lifetime of your factory and the dependencies. Does the factory have longer life time then your dependencies? (i.e. container lifetime but your dependencies are transient or scoped) Then you need to do the resolving for each call to the create method. Referencing the container in factories is okay and the only place where its okay to use them (outside of bootstrapper). Factory implementation is part of the application layer, not your business/domain layer (only interface of it resides there)